# 401(unauthorized error ) while invoking(consuming) a REST URL from ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

i am new to React and I have following code to invoke a REST URL from React Js .

```
const encodedString = Buffer.from('password').toString('base64');
    handleClick = () => {
    axios.post('URL', {
      auth: {
        username: "username",
        password: encodedString
      },
      data: {
        CDO_Office: "Yes"
      },
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(encodedString);
      });
```

The following error is coming.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:59)
```

Comment: This is a *server side* error. This status code is commonly related to wrong o not present authentication.
Maybe you'll find details in the network tab, inspecting the failed response

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server configuration, what types of authentication it supports/allows.
Many services do not allow basic authentication (with plain username + password in the header)

[See how many types are there :)](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/)